# Hide div when clicking the main div, but not when clicking child divs, hrefs, spans etc

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So, when you click the blue content, I want to hide it, but not if you click a child element, like a h2, a, p, etc. Is this possible?

Please see the fiddle

**html**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div v-if="modal" id="content" @click="toggle">
          <h3>
            Name
          </h3>
          <span>
            <a href="">Like this (don't close if clicked)</a>
          </span>
      </div>
      <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**.js**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    modal: true
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function( ){
        this.modal = !this.modal
    }
  }
});
```

**.css**

```
a {
  color: white
}
#content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/awu752mr/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that is what the `v-on:click.self` modifier does. [See here in the docs.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

Answer (score 1):

As @LShapz answered, the modifier=`.self` should be the recommended approach (Vue Style).

Another way is compare `$event.target === $event.currentTarget` (not recommended for your use case, but you may use these two properties for some other situations in future).

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  data: {
   modal: true
  },
  methods: {
   toggle: function(ev){
     if(ev.target === ev.currentTarget) this.modal = !this.modal
    }
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  color: white
}
#content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="modal" id="content" @click="toggle($event)">
    <h3>
      Name
    </h3>
    <span>
      <a href="">Like this</a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>
</div>
```